# I have a large spreadsheet and need to paste several rows between each row there now

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My spreadsheet has over 4,000 rows. Each row there now is right next to each other with no blank rows.

I have a block of rows and columns that I need inserted in between each row there now. I can do this manually by inserting an empty row and pasting with insert so it adds and inserts everything from the clipboard.

It's taking far too long to do it manually. Anyone have an idea on how I can do this quickly?

```
1. data1,blue,info
2. data2,green,info
3. data3,purple,info
4. data4,black,info
5. data5,red,info
```

INTO

```
1. data1,blue,info
2. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
3. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
4. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
5. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
6. data2,green,info
7. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
8. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
9. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
10. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
11. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
12. data3,purple,info
13. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
14. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
15. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
16. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
17. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
18. data4,black,info
19. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
20. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
21. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
22. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
23. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
24. data5,red,info
25. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
26. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
27. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
28. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
29. clipboard,copy,pasta,all,the,same
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might be able to simplify this by not using Excel.

Personally, I would use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or something similar that can record and playback a macro. Here's how to go..

With your spreadsheet (saved as .csv), open the .csv file and put the repeating text in your paste buffer. Then position your cursor at the beginning of the line and start recording a macro (click the red dot on toolbar). Use the end key or keystroke to move the cursor to the end of line, hit return to add a new line and then paste and move to the start of the next line of the old spreadsheet and click to finish the recording. You can then playback the recording N times until you have processed the whole file. When you are done, click save and then open the saved file with Excel and resume business as usual with Excel.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. Trying it now and will report back. Thanks.

Comment: You rock. Been on this for weeks, all fixed in 10min. thank you!

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked out for you! It would have been rough to do with Excel only--possible, but difficult. Well, at least it would have been rough to do in the ways I can think of...it's certainly possible that someone who knows Excel inside and out would knock it out quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In the next column, add a counter.  If you recognize the criteria that means you need to add another row, don't increment the counter.  Otherwise do.

Then, in the column after that, use Index to pull the correct row of data based on the counter.  If there's a duplicate counter value (which means it's time for your extra row of data), grab that row instead.

Then value paste the results.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your answer but it's over my head. Can you elaborate for a newbie? I don't even know where counters are or how to find any of that.

Comment: A counter is just a formula that keeps track of some number. I can give a better answer, but first I need to know: how do you know when it's time to add one of your rows of data?  Or, said another way, how do you know what order the rows go in?